# Getting printer IP Address from Server\PrinterName

Tags: .net, networking, printing, ip

I have a printer installed on the network, and I am looking for a method of resolving the IP address to the name and vice versa.

So firstly the printer is plugged into a network socket. It has its own name and a static IP Address.
Like this, I can send text to it by opening a connection to the IP Address and firing a stream of data (ZPL) to it.

Secondly - the printer is installed on a print server.
\\PRINT_SERVER\Windows_Printer_Name
Checking in the properties I can find the IP Address of it under 'Ports' and 'Configure Port'. (Instead of a local port like COM1 or LPT1, it uses a TCP/IP 'port' which is an IP Address)

I need an automated way of finding this IP Address from the windows path.

Well, what I ACTUALLY need to do is to work the other way round. From an IP Address, find the server/name - but I can see that being not so easy..

I'm working in .NET, so a method through that would be perfect, but I could possibly live with parsing something from the command line if necessary.
Assuming it is possible at all?

Thanks

---

Edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

a command line argument from way back then used to be nbtstat which "Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP connections using NBT (NetBIOS over TCP/IP)" with the -A switch

```
nbtstat -A 192.168.0.1
```

assuming your server ipname is 192.168.0.1

getting ip from servername would be to use ping :)

```
ping servername
```

Comment: But my printer is installed on the server as \\server\a_name_the_admin_chose - not the device name on the network -  the IP of the printer is not the IP of the print server. If I delete the windows driver it is still a valid network identity

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but anyone interested a command line script. This lists printer's queue name and port value. I think real IP address is not that easy to resolve, port value is not always IP address, sometimes has 1.2.3.4_IP suffix or IP_ prefix string.

```
' c:> cscript -nologo scriptname.vbs

Option Explicit

Dim StdOut: Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Dim owshNetwork: Set owshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim oPrinters
Dim idx

Set oPrinters = owshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

for idx=0 to oPrinters.count/2-1
    StdOut.WriteLine "Name=" & oPrinters.Item(idx*2+1) & ", Port=" & oPrinters.Item(idx*2)
next
```